# Paso automatico de input

Tags: javascript, css, html5, materialize

me encuentro con el desarrollo de un proyecto en JavaScript, HTML y CSS, y tengo una duda. Os comento, estoy utilizando `Materialize`, y tengo una serie de `inputs`, los cuales necesito que se pasen automáticamente de uno a otro, una vez que se escribe en ellos, las posibles respuestas que se escribe son caracteres sueltos y la palabra "NADA" . Por ejemplo: La casa es _erde y hay una _aca.(Siendo _ un input), si contesto el primero, se debería pasar automáticamente al siguiente input, estando este input en vacio y dando la posibilidad de escribir sobre él. Para contestar pongo en el valor de los inputs el valor que haya en los tags NFC `document.activeElement.value=valor;`, por tanto la escritura no se hace por teclado, así que descartamos `keyup`. El código es el siguiente:

```
mostrarEjercicio:function (nombreEjercicio,textoEjercicio){
  var text=textoEjercicio;
  var textSeparado=textoEjercicio.split("@");
  var nInput=textSeparado.length-1;
  var idInput=0;

  for (var i=0;i<text.length;i++){
  // Genero inputs
    if(text.charAt(i)=="@"){
      var inputN='<input id="'+idInput+'" type="text" readonly>'
      text = text.replace("@", inputN);
      idInput++;
    }
  }

  var cadena = '<div id="mostrarTextoAlumno" align="center"><h3>'+ nombreEjercicio +'</h3><div class="card-panel cyan lighten-5"><h4 style="color:black;">'+ text + '</h4></div>';
  cadena=cadena+'<div align="center" id="mostrarSolucion">';
  cadena=cadena+'<button id="verBorradorBtn" class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit">Ver borrador<i class="material-icons right">edit</i></button> ';
  cadena=cadena+'</div></div>';
  $('#messageDiv').append(cadena);


},
```

Gracias por la ayuda de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que estás buscando hacer esto:

```js
$(':input').keyup(function(){
  $(this).next().focus();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="input1">
<input type="text" id="input2">
<input type="text" id="input3">
<input type="text" id="input4">
<input type="text" id="input5">
<input type="text" id="input6">
```

Si no es así, comentanos.

Comment: Buenas, gracias por contestar. No es esto exactamente lo que quiero, he editado la pregunta para que se entienda mejor. Lo que me gustaría, es que una vez que se escribe un input (se escribe por medio de tags NFC, eso ya esta controlado), se pasa al siguiente input dando la posibilidad de escribir, es decir, el input al que se pasa debería estar vacío y estar activo para escribir. Espero haberme explicado bien

Comment: @VíctorRubénGómezGarcía he cambiado el código. Es eso?

Comment: keyup es para cuando pulso una tecla del teclado verdad? Sin embargo, yo no escribo por teclado, sino que inserto el valor del tag NFC en el input. Alguna forma para que sea en vez de por teclado, por valor? Y sí, es eso lo que quiero, pero como te digo, para hacerlo sin usar el teclado como tal. Muchas gracias por cierto.

Comment: Cual es l aparte exacta donde llenas el input por tag NFC? Se me ocurre que inmediátamente después de haber echo ese proceso de llenado, apliques $('elementoInput').next().focus(); como te sugirió en la respuesta @cooper.